# cannot access git folder

Tags: git, github

i pushed a xcode project today up to my git repository but
somehow i cannot access this project online via webclient.

[image: 6_Hof_Advanced-iOS cant be accessed]

The folder `6_Hof_Advanced-iOS` cant be accessed. i cant 
click on it to brows the folder. What does this sign 
next to the name of the folder mean? why am i not 
allowed to access it?

i pushed the directory from gitbash on my windows computer.
everything seemed to work as always. i pushed this folder
also on another git repository. on the other i can access
the folder without any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That icon indicated that git considers `6_Hof_Advanced-iOS` to be a submodule and not a folder. Did you create a submodule intentionally?

This is also the reason you cannot access it. Unless the `.gitmodules` file is committed to the repository as well with URLs in it like `git://github.com/username/project` GitHub has no way of knowing how to link that directory for viewing.